# How to remove a feature from a product?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

So I am still learning this amazing complex system folks call Hybris, or SAP Commerce, along with lots of other names :)  I ran into a problem and am looking to learn how to get out of it.  I have added four new classifications attributes (Utilization, Fit, Material, Function).  When I went to add them to the products I added a space between them and the numeric code that came after it:

```
$feature1=@Utilization, 445 [$clAttrModifiers]; # Style                                                         
$feature2=@Fit, 446 [$clAttrModifiers]; # Colour                                                        
$feature3=@Material, 447 [$clAttrModifiers]; # Connections                                                   
$feature4=@Function, 448 [$clAttrModifiers]; # Function                                                      
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$feature1;$feature2;$feature3;$feature4;$catalogVersion;
 ;300413166;my;feature;has;a space
```

The problem is I want to take the space out, as seen in the follow code:

```
$feature1=@Utilization,445 [$clAttrModifiers];# Style           
$feature2=@Fit,446 [$clAttrModifiers];# Colour          
$feature3=@Material,447 [$clAttrModifiers];# Connections     
$feature4=@Function,448 [$clAttrModifiers];# Function        
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$feature1;$feature2;$feature3;$feature4;$catalogVersion;
 ;300413166;Bottom;Loose;Yam type;Sportswear
```

When I run both of these scripts together, I get 8 features:

[image: running both scripts]

So how do I remove the four features that have spaces in them?
How do I go about actually removing the first set of features?

Answer (score 0):

Below removes the ClassAttributeAssignment records, which also removes the ProductFeature entries assigned to all products. However, you need to find the correct classification category code (e.g. clasificationCategory1) the attribute (e.g. Utilization, 445) belongs to. The classification category is the grouping/header you will find in the Attributes

```
$classificationCatalog=ElectronicsClassification
$classificationSystemVersion=systemVersion(catalog(id[default=$classificationCatalog]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true,default=$classificationCatalog:1.0]
$classificationCatalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$classificationCatalog]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true]
$class=classificationClass(code,$classificationCatalogVersion)[unique=true]
$attribute=classificationAttribute(code,$classificationSystemVersion)[unique=true]

REMOVE ClassAttributeAssignment[batchmode=true];$class;$attribute
;clasificationCategory1;Utilization, 445
;clasificationCategory1;Fit, 446
```

[image]

You can also remove the ProductFeature entries (for all products) like this, but it doesn't remove the ClassAttribute assignment.

```
REMOVE ProductFeature[batchmode=true];qualifier[unique=true]
;ElectronicsClassification/1.0/clasificationCategory1.Utilization, 445
```

**Other Reference:**

- Classification System API: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8b7ad17c86691014aa0ee2d228c56dd1.html